# How to exclude logs in Jboss

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I try to avoid in my test stand a lot of useless logs.

In Java classes we have

```
package my.package

public class MyClass {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
  ....
}
```

in JBOSS_HOME...../standalong.xml

I try like

```
<logger category="my.package">
     <level name="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

or

```
<logger category="my.package">
     <level name="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

or

```
<logger category="my.package">
     <level name="SEVERE"/>
</logger>
```

or

```
<logger category="my.package" use-parent-handlers="false">
     <level name="OFF"/>
</logger>
```

or

```
<logger category="my.package" use-parent-handlers="false">
     <level name="ERROR"/>
     <handlers>
        <handler name="FILE"/>
      </handlers>
</logger>
```

nothing works.

Can someone help with that ? :)

Comment: What issue are you seeing? When you made these changes, was the server running?

Comment: I did restart each time. Nothing happened... every logs were the same

Comment: Do you include any logging configuration files in your deployment?

Comment: Nope. It generates via JBoss as logging.properties

Comment: There is no reason that it shouldn't work then. It's better to use CLI to add the logger then you don't need to restart the server. However, it should work if you stop the server, make the change, then restart it.